# Raycaster causes Freezing in Unity Using Oculus SDK and OVRPlayerController

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, oculus

I am creating a scene in Unity using the Oculus SDK and XR Plugin. My scene works well in the Quest 2 including 2 VFX I have added and sound effects. I am following a LinkedIn course about VR UI - and it suggests copying EventSystem and OVRGazePointer from an Oculus > UI example scene into your scene - when I do this, the scene now freezes for a moment every 3 seconds or so. That happens even just by adding it to the scene before hooking it up - and it happens after I hook it up properly to the controllers as well. When I remove these two game objects it goes back to working perfectly. Would anyone have any pointers as to what to check or what I'm doing wrong?

I tried following a YouTube tutorial that used ControllerInteractors which gave me the same exact issue.

My scene is quite large - so I am wondering if the problem is the pointer being rendered on distant objects, or the raycast having more geometry to contend with? Although like I say, the scene itself runs fine - I even followed a number of optimisation steps - but this made no difference. If I build the UI scene that I copied the objects out of that also works in the headset - but I have to say I am a little lost at even what steps to take to try and troubleshoot this. From what I can see there are no errors being generated - and it does seem to just be something that is blocking the whole scene each time it happens. This also happens with my hands still or pointing at the floor.

The following is my Profiler output after adding the offending objects - the spikes would seem consistent with a recurring freeze:
[image]

**Edit:**
Additional Deep Profiler screen:
[image]

Comment: When you run the Unity Profiler, what does it show is using up so much time during those spikes?

Comment: My UI screen is semi-transparent if that would make a difference?

Comment: Edited to be profiler from the actual apk running in the Quest 2 - there is a very long delay that looks like it is related to scripts

Comment: It looks like it's EventSystem.Update which would make sense as that's one of the objects I added that is causing an issue - just digging into that script

Comment: Try the deep profiler to see if you can drill down into what the update is calling.

Comment: Thank you for your pointers because this has at least helped me feel like I have some idea. I added a screenshot from after turning on deep profiler - I also have a UI screen that is the only one that the pointer interacts with - and if I turn it off the frame rate is fine - so it is just struggling from this one small UI screen..